# getting null when Parse 12 Hour Format using Date.js

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
Date.parse("12:59:00 AM").toString("HH:mm:ss") 
output="12:59:00" 


Date.parse("12:59:00 PM").toString("HH:mm:ss")//Getting Null 
output="Unable to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference"
```

getting null when Parse 12 Hour Format using Date.js

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/j2nmD/

Working fine at my end

**JS:-**

```
console.log(Date.parse("12:59:00 AM").toString("HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(Date.parse("12:59:00 PM").toString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: I am using is there browser compability

Comment: on which browser you are getting the issue?

Comment: in my apllication i m simply alert like this alert(Date.parse("12:43:00 PM")); return false;

Comment: try alerting `Date.parse("12:59:00 AM").toString("HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: yes i have tried it alert(Date.parse("12:43:00 PM").toString("HH:mm:ss")); but getting error Line: 97
Error: Unable to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference

Comment: which version of IE you are using?